# How to update Linq result with in the list, without assign other data table process itself get another one result

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, c#-4.0

I got the LINQ Result with the form of list, I have to update that list with out assign another one data table and after that I have new list from the old list.

I had to developed the C# code it is fine to work:

```
var L1=(from cm in CommonTables select cm);
L1.Where(T=> T.Address == null).ToList().ForEach(T=> T.Address="Address1");
```

In that above code is working but in VB.NET how to make develop that code.

I had to try that below code but the end result is same as the Old one:

```
dim L1 = (From cm in commontables select cm)
L1.Where(Function(T) T.Address is nothing).ToList().ForEach(Function(T) T.Address="Address1")
```

If any other possible way for update result.

Comment: Try to assign the List to a variable before ForEach. L2 = L1.Where(Function(T) T.Address is nothing).ToList(); L2.ForEach(Function(T) T.Address="Address1"); Console.Write(L2.First().Address)

Comment: I am already do that, but it is not working @jlvaquero

Comment: Maybe some value/reference issue? If the object passed as parameter to ForEach(T) function is a local copy and not a reference to the original you are not modifing the object in L1, you are modifing a copy and discarting it when ForEach scope ends.

Comment: I have only modify Linq Query result, that one is not affect to the DB, this is my core concept. @jlvaquero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It working

```
dim L1 = (From cm in commontables select cm)
L1.Where(Function(T) T.Address is nothing).ToList()
For i =0 to L1.count-1 step 1
   L1(i).Address="Address1"
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I had done it in other way for that problem

```
dim L1 = (From cm in commontables select cm)
L1.Where(Function(T) T.Address is nothing).ToList()
For Each item in L1
   item.Address="Address1"
Next
```